# How to solve NullPointerException in initialising intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to initialise an intent in a function like below :

```
public void playNextOver() {
    songInfo detail = (songInfo) songAdapter.getItem(globalPos);

    songTitle = detail.getTitle();

    songPath = detail.getPath();
    songId = String.valueOf(detail.getID());
    songArtist = detail.getArtist();

    Intent globalIntentTemp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), songPlay.class);
    globalIntentTemp.putExtra("SONG_ID", songId);
    globalIntentTemp.putExtra("SONG_TITLE", songTitle);
    globalIntentTemp.putExtra("SONG_ARTIST", songArtist);
    globalIntentTemp.putExtra("SONG_PATH", songPath);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(globalIntentTemp);
}
```

I am doing this inside an activity.

But it is giving me following error at runtime on this statement

```
Intent globalIntentTemp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), songPlay.class);
```

09-06 00:32:19.441 25790-25790/com.example.coderahul.beats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.coderahul.beats, PID: 25790
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
                                                                                 at com.example.coderahul.beats.playlistManager.playNextOver(playlistManager.java:503)
                                                                                 at com.example.coderahul.beats.songPlay$2.onClick(songPlay.java:703)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20299)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5657)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:990)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:785)

I don't know what to do since  I am new to Android. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire activity and the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: Question is updated please have a look.

Comment: it still does not have information about the state in which method is called

Comment: Please post your function `getAppContext()`

Comment: Actually it is getApplicationContext() instead of getAppContext() and thanks @hqt for understanding :)

Comment: Before complaining about the behavior of others, focus first on your own behavior. I asked you to post the entire activity. You decided not to do that. As a result, others decided to give you a generic response, since giving you specific help is difficult without a [mcve]. If I had to guess, `playlistManager` is not a valid activity. For example, perhaps you created an instance of `playlistManager` via its constructor, which will result in an invalid activity.